# ViewPager с высотой wrap_content с двумя RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

Требуется создать `ViewPager` с двумя `RecyclerView` выдвигаюшийся под тулбаром с затемнением как у диалога. Добавляю `FrameLayout` с затемненным `View` и самим `ViewPager` поверх декора. Добавляю `marginTop` с высотой тулбара. Вот что получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`RecyclerView` теряет скролл если высоты экрана не хватает. Причем в эффектe `overScroll` заметно, что высота не обрывается, а просто перестает работать скролл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используется [кастомный `ViewPager`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20784791/5698345) с переопределенным `onMeasure`. В манифесте у активности стоит

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Но это, думаю, ни на что не влияет

Comment: Note the Math.max(height, 1). That fixes annoying bug that ViewPager does not update displayed page (shows it blank), when previous page has zero height (i. e. null drawable in the CustomImageView), each odd swipe back and forth between two pages.

©https://stackoverflow.com/a/14778177/4794368

Comment: @qwabra, тоесть в моем случае надо в адаптере переопределить `setPrimaryItem` и получить высоту ресайклера. Потом ставить контейнеру `layoutParams` указав высоту `Math.max(recyclerHeight, 1)` а почему 1? это константа `WRAP_CONTENT`?

Comment: я вообще не представляю о чём тут идёт речь :) но (when previous page has zero height) переводится как (когда предыдущая страница имеет нулевую высоту) могу перевести весь текст как ответ

Comment: @qwabra, дайте ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я слабо представляю о чём тут идёт речь, а так же не имею возможно проверить озвученные далее мысли.

здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/14778177/4794368 говорится о каком-то баге, проявляющемся когда предыдущая страница имеет нулевую высоту. автор приводит простое решение проблемы:

```
pager.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, Math.max(height, 1)));
```

`Math.max(height, 1)` - `Math.max` возвращает максимальное значение, то есть если `height` будет меньше единицы - эта функция вернёт 1, таким образом минимальная высота, передаваемая в функцию `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` = 1.

что инетересно, есть issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36969648
в котором говорится:

"Status: Won't Fix (Obsolete)"
"Статус: не будет исправлено (устарело)" 2014 год

"Obsolete? Ok, so, what is best solution to..."
"Устарело? Ок, какое лучшее решение для ..." 2016 год

так же, рекомендую обратить внимание на вот этот ответ
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14983747/4794368
там предложен другой способ на основе `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`

```
widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
```

и `MeasureSpec.AT_MOST`

```
firstChild.measure(widthMeasureSpec, 
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
```

вместо `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED`

Comment: собственно, это направило меня на правильный путь. сейчас разбираюсь. спасибо

Comment: а если задать высоту в пол экрана, скрол будет работать? если да - я тут смотрю есть такая штука `int height = maxChildHeight + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();` значит есть и для margin, наверное ...

Comment: как раз высота в пол экрана не нравится заказчику

Comment: я к тому, чтобы проверить прокрутка пропадает в том случае, если выходит за рамки экрана, если это так `getPaddingTop` и что-то около , в общем уточнять расчет высоты